# python asyncio - how to wait for a cancelled shielded task?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

If I have a coroutine which runs a task which should not be cancelled, I will wrap that task in `asyncio.shield()`.

It seems the behavior of `cancel` and `shield` is not what I would expect. If I have a task wrapped in `shield` and I cancel it, the `await`-ing coroutine returns from that `await` statement immediately rather than awaiting for the task to finish as `shield` would suggest. Additionally, the task that was run with `shield` continues to run but its future is now cancelled an not `await`-able.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.shield):

> except that if the coroutine containing it is cancelled, the Task running in something() is not cancelled. From the point of view of something(), the cancellation did not happen. Although its caller is still cancelled, so the “await” expression still raises a CancelledError.

These docs do not imply strongly that the caller is cancelled potentially *before* the callee finishes, which is the heart of my issue.

What is the proper method to `shield` a task from cancellation and then wait for it to complete before returning.

It would make more sense if `asyncio.shield()` raised the `asyncio.CancelledError` after the `await`-ed task has completed, but obviously there is some other idea going on here that I don't understand.

Here is a simple example:

```
import asyncio

async def count(n):
  for i in range(n):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def t():
  try:
    await asyncio.shield(count(5))
  except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print('This gets called at 3, not 5')

  return 42

async def c(ft):
  await asyncio.sleep(3)

  ft.cancel()

async def m():
  ft = asyncio.ensure_future(t())
  ct = asyncio.ensure_future(c(ft))

  r = await ft

  print(r)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(m())

# Running loop forever continues to run shielded task
# but I'd rather not do that
#loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> It seems the behavior of `cancel` and `shield` is not what I would expect. If I have a task wrapped in `shield` and I cancel it, the `await`-ing coroutine returns from that `await` statement immediately rather than awaiting for the task to finish as `shield` would suggest. Additionally, the task that was run with `shield` continues to run but its future is now cancelled an not `await`-able.

Conceptually `shield` is like a bullet-proof vest that absorbs the bullet and protects the wearer, but is itself destroyed by the impact. `shield` absorbs the cancellation, and reports itself as canceled, raising a `CancelledError` when asked for result, but allows the protected task to continue running. (Artemiy's answer explains the implementation.)

Cancellation of the future returned by `shield` could have been implemented differently, e.g. by completely ignoring the cancel request. The current approach ensures that the cancellation "succeeds", i.e. that the canceller can't tell that the cancellation was in fact circumvented. This is by design, and it makes the cancellation mechanism more consistent on the whole.

> What is the proper method to shield a task from cancellation and then wait for it to complete before returning

By keeping two objects: the original task, and the shielded task. You pass the shielded task to whatever function it is that might end up canceling it, and you await the original one. For example:

```
async def coro():
    print('starting')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('done sleep')

async def cancel_it(some_task):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    some_task.cancel()
    print('cancellation effected')

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    real_task = loop.create_task(coro())
    shield = asyncio.shield(real_task)
    # cancel the shield in the background while we're waiting
    loop.create_task(cancel_it(shield))
    await real_task

    assert not real_task.cancelled()
    assert shield.cancelled()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

The code waits for the task to fully complete, despite its shield getting cancelled.

Comment: This is interesting. I don't think the docs do enough to explain this. If the cancelled coroutine is finishes before the shielded task finishes (in `run_until_complete`) then the shielded task is not actually waited for. Why doesnt the implementation of `shield` just do `await real_task`?

Comment: @shane If `shield` alyways awaited the task it protects, then its cancellation would be a no-op. (The new docs [explain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#shielding-from-cancellation) how to get such effect if needed.) This would mean that e.g. `asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(foo()), 1)` would always wait for `foo()` to finish, which is undesirable. As written, the timeout is respected, but cancellation causes `foo()` to continue running in the background. This is quite useful, although the docs could do a better job of presenting the case.

Comment: In other words, if the task returned by `shield()` **didn't** return immediately when cancelled, it would completely break the semantics of cancellation. `shield()` is designed to have that cake (correct cancellation semantics) and eat it too (the wrapped task not actually getting cancelled), at the price of introducing some confusion as to the usage.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I still feel the idiom to cancel a task without cancelling a specific subtask(?) wrapped in `asyncio.shield()` is confusing. Maybe asyncio could use another utility function to accomplish this or an optional argument to shield called `wait_complete` or something

Answer (score 8):

> It would make more sense if asyncio.shield() raised the asyncio.CancelledError after the await-ed task has completed, but obviously there is some other idea going on here that I don't understand.

`asyncio.shield`

- creates a dummy future, that may be cancelled
- executes the wrapped coroutine as future and bind to it a callback on done to setting a result for the dummy future from the completed wrapped coroutine
- returns the dummy future

You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L830)

> What is the proper method to shield a task from cancellation and then wait for it to complete before returning

You should shield `count(5)` future

```
async def t():
  c_ft = asyncio.ensure_future(count(5))
  try:
    await asyncio.shield(c_ft)
  except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print('This gets called at 3, not 5')
    await c_ft

  return 42
```

or `t()` future

```
async def t():
  await count(5)
  return 42    

async def m():
  ft = asyncio.ensure_future(t())
  shielded_ft = asyncio.shield(ft)
  ct = asyncio.ensure_future(c(shielded_ft))

  try:
    r = await shielded_ft
  except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print('Shield cancelled')
    r = await ft
```

Comment: PSA: when linking source in GitHub, hit `y` to convert `.../master/...` in the URL to the specific commit (or use a tag).

Comment: Thanks. That was very useful. I was struggling with this same problem.

Comment: The main part of this: assuming that `t()` will only over be cancelled once (not twice), as is the case if you're using `TaskGroup` for structured concurrency, you should re-wait the original un-shielded task in an `except asyncio.CancelledError` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Shielding a coroutine
we can also shield a task (but this code is about shilding a coroutine)

```
import asyncio

async def task1():
    print("Starting task1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Ending task1")
    print("SUCCESS !!")

async def task2(some_task):
    print("Starting task2")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("Cancelling task1")
    some_task.cancel()
    print("Ending task2")

async def main():
    # coroutines
    co_task1 = task1()

    # creating task from coroutines
    task1_shielded = asyncio.shield(co_task1)  # Create a shielded task1
    task2_obj = asyncio.create_task(coro=task2(task1_shielded))

    await task2_obj
    await task1_shielded

asyncio.run(main())
```

out put:

```
Starting task1
Starting task2
Ending task1
SUCCESS !!
Cancelling task1
Ending task2
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. `task2` sleeps for longer than the task you're interested in waiting for, `task1`, and `main` waits for `task2` so of course `task1` completes before `main` does. That's not because you've fundamentally avoided the waiter (`main()`) from being interrupted by cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't address the problem that the enclosing coroutine could be cancelled more than once. This can happen if you're using [task groups](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup), which are the recommended way to safely structure your code; if two enclosing task groups (i.e. both a parent and a grandparent) get exceptions from sibling tasks then you could get `asyncio.CancelledError` even within an `except asyncio.CancelledError:` block. It can also happen if you manually call the `cancel()` method on the task, with enough time in between, although that would be less common. Either way, you need to use a `while` loop to handle this in full generality.

Here is a fixed version that successfully waits even if cancelled multiple times:

```
async def shield_and_wait(fn):
    done_event = asyncio.Event()
    fn = asyncio.ensure_future(fn)
    fn.add_done_callback(lambda _: done_event.set())
    cancelled_exception = None
    while True:
        try:
            await done_event.wait()
            break
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            cancelled_exception = e
    if cancelled_exception:
        raise asyncio.CancelledError from cancelled_exception
    return await fn
```

Use it like this:

```
x = await shield_and_wait(my_function(2))
```

Some design notes:

- You might want to simply `return fn` rather than `return await fn`. That way you can inspect the result (e.g. by checking its [`exception()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.exception) before getting the [`result()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.result)).
- I'm being a bit pedantic with `raise asyncio.CancelledError from cancelled_exception`. Just `raise asyncio.CancelledError` or `raise cancelled_exception` would work fine. The choice I used gives slightly better traceback information in the case that the exception ends up uncaught, but hopefully that never happens anyway (because hopefully it is caught by an enclosing task group).
- I considered being extra pedantic by capturing all caught `asyncio.CancelledError` instances in a list and raising them in a [`BaseExceptionGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-groups). But that confused task groups, which ended up re-raising their own cancellation exceptions.
- You may wish to consider [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/) (an alternative to asyncio) or [AnyIO](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/) (a Trio API for either Trio or asyncio – on Trio it just falls through to the original code, while on asyncio it contains a complete reimplementation of the API). These have a much simpler and safer cancellation API, including shielding that really works. Note that you should not use the above function within an AnyIO task group because it uses [level-based cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060510/what-is-the-difference-between-anyio-taskgroup-and-asyncio-taskgroup/78060511#78060511) so the above `while:` loop will spin constantly (but then you don't need this function anyway because you can just use an AnyIO shielded cancellation scope).