# Async subprocess context manager

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, contextmanager

I want an async context manager that ensures the managed process has finished before exiting by either graceful or forceful termination, and regardless of cancellation. For example,

```py
async def sleep(duration):
  proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('sleep', str(duration))
  async with manage_process(proc):
     ...
  # proc either finished, was terminated, or killed.
```

This best I've got so far is:

```py
@asynccontextmanager
async def manage_process(
    proc: asyncio.subprocess.Process,
    timeout: Optional[float] = None,
) -> AsyncIterator[asyncio.subprocess.Process]:
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = 1.0

    try:
        yield proc
    finally:
        try:
            proc.terminate()
        except ProcessLookupError:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                await asyncio.shield(asyncio.wait_for(proc.wait(), timeout))
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                is_done = False
                is_cancelled = True
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                is_done = False
                is_cancelled = False
            else:
                is_done = True
                is_cancelled = False

            if not is_done:
                try:
                    proc.kill()
                except ProcessLookupError:
                    pass
                else:
                    await asyncio.shield(proc.wait())

            if is_cancelled:
                raise asyncio.CancelledError()
```

I'm not sure I'm handling the cancellation correctly. I've used `asyncio.shield()` not I'm not sure I do it correctly.

Comment: Is the code not working? Are you just looking to improve it?

Comment: @dim The code doesn't crash. I'm not sure if it follows the cancellation contract correctly. I guess I'm asking for review.

Comment: If your intention is to guarantee that the subprocess has exited by the time the process manager finishes executing, I think you have a hole because the task can be canceled while waiting in the second `proc.wait()`. For example, the first `proc.wait()` can time out, and cancellation arrives during the second `proc.wait()`. `asyncio.shield()` will protect `wait()` from cancellation, but it won't protect your task, which will immediately receive (and propagate) a `CancelledError`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think you're really getting at what I don't know about cancellation. Are you saying the `shield()` sort of detaches the task and immediately raises `CancelledError`. I'd guessed that `shield` waits for the task and then raises `CancelledError`, but thinking about that, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think you're quite close to understanding it. Yes, the former is true, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511210/1600898) (and the other answer to the same question) for details. If you want to ensure that `proc.wait()` finishes, you probably need some sort of `while` loop around the second invocation of `proc.wait()`, replacing `await asyncio.shield(proc.wait())` with something [like this](https://pastebin.com/bxBMyWKm).

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks I've got a new impl with `while` loops. But, I'm not sure how to add it to this question. I've been shouted at before about updating questions with new versions.

Comment: @PeterSutton I guess you can always make an edit and append the new code accompanied by an explanation of the update. The real question is what is the actual question at this point? StackOverflow is not about code review (there is [another site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that), you're supposed to ask a specific question about something you don't understand or have problems with. If you can formulate such a question, it would make a perfect edit.